# Why would I have more video interfaces than physically available?

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics

I have a NUC 5i3RYH.

According to [Intel Specs](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-nuc5i3ryh.html) and my eyes, I have two ports:

1. 1x Mini HDMI 1.4a
2. 1x Mini DisplayPort 1.2

I connected a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter to the Mini DisplayPort port and ran `xrandr -display :0 -q` to query the Xorg detected stuff, but I end up with three connections:

1. DP1 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
2. HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
3. HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 390mm

The output overscans (terminal login is cut off before X Server even starts) on two Samsung TVs that I tried. Interestingly, the HDMI direct option works as expected.

Comment: Because the interfaces visible to software depend on what the chipset supports. Not all of those pins of the graphics chip have to be actually connected on the motherboard/graphics card.